# error of opening a file located in a remote server from python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, windows-7

I need to access read a csv file located in a server from python 3.2 on win7.

The file name is

```
    csv_file = 
    file_loc = '\\serverName.myCompanyName.com\\mypath\\Files\\myfile.csv'

    with open(file_loc , 'r') as csv_file  # error !!!
         csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
```

error:

```
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\serverName.myCompanyName.com\\mypath\\Files\\myfile.csv'
```

But, I can access the folder and open the file from win 7 .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*UNC Paths* require two backslashes to start, and due to escaping, you only have one in the above code.

Try this:

```
file_loc = '\\\\serverName.myCompanyName.com\\mypath\\Files\\myfile.csv'
```

Or this:

```
file_loc = r'\\serverName.myCompanyName.com\mypath\Files\myfile.csv'
```

The latter is a *raw string* in which backslashes don't need to be escaped (among others).

The path with which you can successfully access the file using *Explorer* or similar, that's the same path that should be present in your code after escaping is taken into account. (i.e. what you get when you `print` the value).